# How we can create multi touch in android?

Tags: android, image, multi-touch

Can we create multi touch in Android?
I have multiple images and have to drag and drop that images together on
my device. Is it possible? if it is possible then any ideas would help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nidhi, Good Morning, As per My Knowledge, android phones does not supports for multi touch. This is possible in iPhone.

Comment: Is there no chance to multi touch? but why not?

Comment: I guess is native dependent functionality, when android it self is not allowing for multi touch, you can not achieve it. However you might achieve in another way like User PolamReddy suggested you. In case of iPhone, the MAC it self allows the multi touch functionality. so it is possible in iPhone's case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to intercept touch events in your view. Implement an `onTouchListener` and inside the function:

```
 onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
    int count=getPointerCount();
   if(count >1){
      // it means there are more than 1 point touched on the screen.
   }
}
```

This is available only since API 5